# why would ssh work the first, second, and third time but time out on the fourth?

Tags: ssh, timeout

I would like to be able to use `ssh`, but I end up getting an timeout intermittently.

Here is how I can reproduce the error on the server in question:

```
$ ssh <user>@<server> ls # returns contents as expected
$ ssh <user>@<server> ls # " " " " 
$ ssh <user>@<server> ls # " " " " 
$ ssh <user>@<server> ls # times out
ssh: connect to host <server> port 22: Connection timed out
```

if I wait about 10 minutes or so, it will work again for the first three times. The system administrators have not been able to identify the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably a connection rate limit, imposed by the platform's equivalent of [`iptables`](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/187). Three connections per minute is the most common setting, which looks suspiciously like what you're seeing.

Comment: thanks, are you referring to the `iptables --limit rate` settings? I am finding `man iptables` pretty dense, e.g. 'limit : This module matches at a limited rate using a token bucket filter'

Comment: No, that limits the traffic rate. I'm talking about limits to the connection rate from distinct source IP addresses. Check the manpage under `recent` and look at `hitcount` and `seconds`. (The link in my answer has examples.)

Comment: When asked, the sysadmins say 'I can almost guarantee you that is the case.' and 'I totally forgot about the ssh firewall rule'. Thanks for helping us identify the issue.